# Why are the props not injected into component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

react/redux newbie here. Trying to build a todo app and have a container component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Input from '../components/InputText'
import addTodo from '../actions/addTodoAction'

export class InputText extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    prop: PropTypes
  }
}

export default connect(null, {addTodo})(Input)
```

The 'stateless' component Input looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const InputText = ({addTodo}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text'></input>
            <button onClick={this.props.addTodo}>add todo</button>
        </div>
    )
}

//question :define proptype for action?
InputText.propTypes = {
    addTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default InputText
```

This is the actioncreator:

```
const addTodo = (param) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  payload: param.text
})

export default addTodo;
```

When I run the app I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addTodo' of undefined

So looks like the props are not passed in. What am I doing wrong? Link to 
[githubrepo](https://github.com/dimitri-a/todo_mvc_scratch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use this.props.addTodo, just use it simply `<button onClick={addTodo}>add todo</button>`.

You have directly taken `addTodo` by destructuring the props.